# Dynamically loading image resource in angular directive always errors on initial load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive I built to convert 3-digit ISO-3316 country codes into a flag and the country name. I use it like so:

```
<country-with-flag data="840">
```

My directive looks like this:

```
.directive('countryWithFlag', ['countryCodes', function(countryCodes) {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<img src="assets/images/flags/{{data | numericToAlphaCode}}.png"> {{data | numericToCountry}}',
    }
}])
```

`numericToAlphaCode` is a filter which would convert `840` into the 3316-alpha2 code which is `"US"` in this instance.

The directive results in this: [image: Flag & country name]

This works perfectly, *except* that when the page loads I have an error in the console before angular converts the expression into something useful:

[image: error]

Why is this occurring and how can I avoid this error from being generated? I assume I need to do something in the `link` but I'm a little confused as to how that would work, especially because the error occurs before `link` even gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc), it should prevent loading of the asset until the string is interpolated

```
template: '<img ng-src="assets/images/flags/{{data | numericToAlphaCode}}.png"> {{data | numericToCountry}}',
```

Comment: Well, that fixed it pretty easily! Can't believe I missed that directive.